# StringTokenizer not working

Tags: java, android

I have a string as

`str=123|apple|apple|apple|dog$`

i like to seperate string using "|" character.

```
    String str = "123|apple|apple|apple|dog$";
    StringTokenizer strString = new StringTokenizer(str..nextToken(), "|");
    int i;
    while (strString.hasMoreElements()) {
        if (i == 0)
            str1 = Loginstring.nextToken();
        else if (i == 1)
            str2 = Integer.Loginstring.nextToken();
        else if (i == 2) {
            str3 = Loginstring.nextToken();
            break;
        }
        i = i + 1;
    }
```

but it exit on first loop onwards(that means it exit from loop if i more than 1),, really i dont know y its happens, whats wrong with it

Comment: you could provide a better code sample of what are you doing... (it isn't compiling, and it isn't complete)

Comment: you can use `str.split("\\|")` to split by `|`

Comment: str=123|apple|apple|apple|dog$ is my string . i want to seperate string for "|" character using StringTokenizer ,, how to do it

Comment: of course it exits.  when i==2, you have a "break" statement which will break out of the while loop.

Comment: You create a string tokenizer called `strString` but never advance it with a call to `nextToken`.  All of the `nextToken` calls are against something call `Loginstring`.  So you loop 3 times and your `if(i==2)` block causes a break in the loop.

Comment: Also noticed that when you create `strString` the string you pass in is the result of the first call to `str.nextToken`.  So that means `strString` is created with a string that does not contain your `|` token, meaning your `while(strString.hasMoreElements())` should be false.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this is what you are trying to achieve

```
String str1 = "", str2 = "", str3 = "", str4 = "", str5 = "";
String str = "123|apple|apple|apple|dog$";
StringTokenizer strString = new StringTokenizer(str, "|");
int k = 0;
while (strString.hasMoreElements()) {
    if (k == 0)
        str1 = strString.nextToken();
    else if (k == 1)
        str2 = strString.nextToken();
    else if (k == 2) {
        str3 = strString.nextToken();
    } else if (k == 3) {
        str4 = strString.nextToken();
    } else if (k == 4) {
        str5 = strString.nextToken();
        break;
    }
    k = k + 1;
}
System.out.println(str1);
System.out.println(str2);
System.out.println(str3);
System.out.println(str4);
System.out.println(str5);
```

but this can be easily done in one statement by

```
String[] tokens = str.split("\\|"); // this is that single statment
for (String token : tokens)
    System.out.println(token);

str1 = tokens[0];
str2 = tokens[1];
str3 = tokens[2];
str4 = tokens[3];
str5 = tokens[4];

System.out.println(str1);
System.out.println(str2);
System.out.println(str3);
System.out.println(str4);
System.out.println(str5);
```

Comment: thanks for the response,, now i got it successfully using your second method

Comment: and i get irritated when i ask question every time in this forum,, actually what is the quality standards for this forum

Comment: @sivanesan don't get irritated. please be patient while preparing your queries. also have a look at first thee sections of [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Answer (score 1):

use `String.split("\\|")` to split the string.

Comment: escaping's only relevant for regexes (i.e. `String.split()`), not StringTokenizer

Comment: Thanks... It is a new thing for me